# How do I create release branch from master, excluding particular branch which is already merge in master

Tags: xcode, git, version-control, bitbucket

I have branches A, B, C, D which were merge in my **master**, I want to create release branch 
  which include A, C, D and I want to exclude B branch changes, so that my **release** branch 
  contains only A, C, B branches. Please could you help me with this. Thank you.

Comment: create branch from master before merge A, D, C, D and merge there branches you need

Comment: Sorry I don't get it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way is to use a desktop client like [Github Desktop](https://desktop.github.com) or [Sourcetree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com). You can create a release branch from your `master` assuming it's merged as follows:

```sh
$ git checkout -b release
```

You can then use the desktop client to revert commits from your `B` branch changes. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The other way is you can do that by UI first you have to revert B Branch from earlier merged after revert you need to take the latest pull of master branch excluding B branch code then create a new branch named as follow.

```
git checkout -b release
```

and last again you need to merge into master branch that excluded B branch so the master branch is again up to date